# Unity3D: How to show mesh in scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

I've c# class:

```
class VisualElement { 
   private GameObject mesh {get; set;};
   public VisualElement(){
      mesh = Gameobject.find("Models/VE");
   }  
   public void showMesh(GameObject player){
      //TODO show mesh
   }
}
```

What I need to do to have my element displayed on the scene?

I can get from the player the position where I want to place the mesh object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the [manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html). Also, [GameObject.Find](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) is for finding GameObjects that are already in the scene. If you want to load an asset from file, use [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).

On the other hand, I'm 90% sure you do not need this class at all. Each time you would create a `VisualElement`, just [instantiate a GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html?from=GameObject) and Unity will do all the work for you.